# jQuery div clicks, catching undesirable clicks

Tags: jquery, asp.net

To make `div`s clickable I use this:

```
$(".clickable").click(function (event) {
    window.location = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

I'm using an `<asp:Repeater>` in asp.NET to create several such `<div>`s.

The problem is that *all* clicks in the div are picked up by this jQuery - I also have an `<asp:Button>` inside the div, for this I want to catch the click as normal and process it in the repeater_ItemCommand event - But this doesn't fire - the page just redirects to the href found in the hyperlink in the div.

Anyway I can stop this and make the button pick up as normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check whether `event.target` is an `input` element (use the `nodeName` property, or call `$(event.target).is(...)`).

If it is, don't do anything in your handler.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing it would be to modify your markup and add another `div` inside of your main `div` that has the anchor tag. Give that the class clickable. And have your button outside of it, like so.

```
<div>
    <div class='clickable'>
        <a href='#'>Link</a>
   </div>
   <asp:button>
</div>
```